# wp_list_pages() ignoring 'child_of' parameter of hierarchical custom post type

Tags: php, wordpress

## Update – fixed it, was a typo

There was a space too much at the end of the array key in my args array for the parameter `child_of`. I didn't correct it in this thread, so it may be useful for anyone who comes here via google.

## Original question

I want to display custom post type entries of a hierarchical custom post type (`capability_type` of `'page'`) which belong to a specific parent ID.

The custom post type is generated with the following code in my functions.php:

```
function custom_post_type() {
    $args = array(
        'supports'              => array( 'title', 'editor', 'comments', 'page-attributes' ),
        'hierarchical'          => true,
        'capability_type'       => 'page',
        'publicly_queryable'    => true,
        'show_ui'               => true,
        'show_in_menu'          => true,
        'public'                => true
    );
    register_post_type( 'wiki', $args );

}
add_action( 'init', 'custom_post_type', 0 );
```

I tried this code, to show only childs of a specific ID:

```
$ultraparentID = 123;
wp_list_pages(array(
    'child_of ' => $ultraparentID,
    'post_type' => 'wiki',
));
```

But this lists **all** the custom post type entries for `wiki` and not only the specified childs of ID `123`. I might be missing something from the docs. But for the [parameters it states](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_list_pages/#parameters) the following for `child_of`:

> Display only the sub-pages of a single page by ID. Default 0 (all pages).

Even though the function is called 'wp_list_**pages**()' this should work for hierarchical post type items (also stated in the docs).

What am I missing? Or is there any error in my code, which I just don't get?

Comment: Although this might not be related to your problem, you might want to be aware that `child_of` includes grandchild and so on. If you only want direct children you should use `parent` instead. https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/161489/12496

Comment: Thanks @ChrisHaas – I definitly want all the grandchildren and great grandchildren and so forth.

Comment: I got the solution – it was a typo in my arguments array for the wp_list_pages() function. There was a space at the end of 'child_of ' ‍♂️

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solution:**
There was a space too much at the end of the array key in my args array for the parameter child_of. I didn't correct it in this thread, so it may be useful for anyone who comes here via google.

**Wrong Code:**

```
wp_list_pages(array(
    'child_of ' => $ultraparentID,
    'post_type' => 'wiki',
));
```

**Correct Code:**

```
wp_list_pages(array(
    'child_of' => $ultraparentID,
    'post_type' => 'wiki',
));
```